# Travelling via Athens Airport to Vienna

Tags: transit, ath

Am transiting through Athens to Vienna, arriving Athens ex Doha on QATAR airways ETA 12:10 pm and departing to Vienna on Austrian ETD 1455, a 2 hour 45 min changeover. The flights are on separate tickets.

We will have to pick up our bags, go through customs and check in given QATAR is One-World and Austria is Star(?) and we cannot book straight through. Any tips? I would not be concerned if our bags were booked through but given that cannot be done I wonder whether I’ve cut things too fine.
Cheers
Frank G

Comment: I assume you booked this as two separate tickets, right?

Comment: Yep, I did, one with Qatar the other with Austria

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure where you see a big problem here. So let's answer all the potential small ones:

1. When checking in you luggage in Doha show your boarding pass for Athens Vienna (you should check in on the web in advance!) and the check in counter in Doha may be able to check you luggage through to Vienna. Airport luggage handling is not tied to airlines. The EU is not the US, there is no rule that says you have to pick up your lugagge on entering the EU.
2. 2h 45min should be enough time change flights.
3. Using seperate tickets is always a gamble. If you did this to save less than a hundred Euros it was not a smart move.